# Applying a fisher transformation and avoid Inf values

Tags: r

I am trying to create some functions in R based on this short document.

https://www.mesasoftware.com/papers/TheInverseFisherTransform.pdf

I firstly normalised the data between -1 and 1. Then I apply the equation. The problem occurs when the highest and lowest values become -Inf and Inf from the normalisation function.

```
> log((1 + +1) / (1 - +1))
[1] Inf
> log((1 + -1) / (1 - -1))
[1] -Inf
```

What I have currently is:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- rnorm(10000, mean = 10, sd = 20)    # randomly generate some data

negPosOneNormalisation <- function(x){
  2 * ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))) - 1        # normalise data -1 and 1
}

normalised_data <- negPosOneNormalisation(data)     # data is now between -1 and 1 bounds

FisherTransform <- function(x){
  (0.5) * log((1 + x) / (1 - x))                    # Apply equation (1) from paper
}

fisher_data <- FisherTransform(normalised_data)     

sum(is.infinite(fisher_data))                      # results give two Inf values

InverseFisherTransform <- function(x){
  y = FisherTransform(x)
  inv_y = (exp**(2*y) - 1) / (e**(2*y) + 1)        # apply equation (2) from paper
}

InverseFisherTransform(fisher_data)                # returns and error due to the Inf values
```

How can I apply such a normalisation function where the maximum is not exactly -1 or +1 but can be -0.99999 and +0.99999 or some epsilon amount above or below the extremes.

I do not want to change the input data but would something like the following still hold:

```
negPosOneNormalisation <- function(x){
  2 * ((x +/- epsilon - min(x +/- epsilon)) / (max(x +/- epsilon) - min(x +/- epsilon))) - 1        # normalise data -1 and 1
}
```

How can I apply the function such that I avoid the -Inf and +Inf problem?

Answer (score 1):

How is about transforming your Inf or -Inf into 0.9999 or -0.9999 after your fisher transformation?

you could do it easily with

```
fisher_data[which(fisher_data==Inf)]<-0.9999
fisher_data[which(fisher_data==-Inf)]<--0.9999
```